# Elm update infinite loop

Tags: elm

New to Elm, so I may be missing something obvious.

I'm working on an Elm application that uses [annaghi/dnd-list](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/annaghi/dnd-list/latest/). I'm encountering an infinite loop of calls to update. This happens when clicking on one element, then another one. Here's the code:

```
config : DnDList.Config Player
config =
    { beforeUpdate = \_ _ list -> list
    , movement = DnDList.Free
    , listen = DnDList.OnDrag
    , operation = DnDList.Swap
    }


system : DnDList.System Player Msg
system =
    DnDList.create config DndMsg


type alias Model =
    { navKey : Nav.Key
    , room : WebData Room
    , dnd : DnDList.Model
    , startError : Maybe String
    }

type Msg
    = RoomReceived (WebData Room)
    | DndMsg DnDList.Msg

...

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        RoomReceived room ->
            ( { model | room = room }, Cmd.none )
        DndMsg message ->
            let
                room = model.room
            in
            case room of
                RemoteData.Success actualRoom ->
                    let
                        ( dnd, players ) =
                            system.update message model.dnd actualRoom.players

                        updatedRoom = RemoteData.map 
                            (\roomData -> 
                                { roomData | players = players }
                            ) room
                    in
                    ( { model | dnd = dnd, room = updatedRoom }
                    , system.commands model.dnd
                    )
                _ ->
                    ( model, Cmd.none )
```

When I change the line `system.commands model.dnd` to `Cmd.none`, then there is no infinite looping call to the update function, but also nothing happens. The message that keeps getting called in the dnd-list library is `GotDropElement (Ok dropElement)`

Again, new to Elm, so this may be a poorly formed question, but any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to add a subscription to listen to mouse events

```
currentSubs : Model -> Sub Msg
currentSubs model =
    case model.page of
        GameRoomPage pageModel ->
            GameRoom.subscriptions pageModel
                |> Sub.map GameRoomMsg
        _ ->
            always Sub.none model

...

main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.application
        { view = view
        , init = init
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = currentSubs
        , onUrlRequest = LinkClicked
        , onUrlChange = UrlChanged
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following the flow from `system.commands`. Probably it is eventually sending again the message `DndMsg` and this is what is causing the issue.

It is usually considered not a good practice to send messages from commands.

In case you cannot solve the issue, having a working example of the problematic code in Ellie (https://ellie-app.com/new) would help.